# Missing .dll files when compiling with notepad++ and minGW

Tags: c, dll, mingw, notepad++

Recently I started coding in C and I tried to find a way to compile with notepad++. After thouroughly installing minGW with some basic upgrades I tried to use a specific code that allows me to compile. 
This code is can be found on thise webpage:
http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2015/08/configure-notepad-to-run-c-cpp-and-java-programs.html
So you can see what I am trying to do.
However when I try to execute the command, it gives me the warning that several .dll files are missing. 
These are the ones: libgmp-10.dll ; libiconv-2.dll ; libmpc-3.dll and libmpfr-4.dll
After some research, I added those files to the bin, lib and libexec folders of the minGW headfolder and it resulted in giving me another missing lib file:
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll

Ok I added that one too and now it starts over saying it is missing libiconv-2.dll
I added all the folders to my PATH and there is nothing else I can think of that is wrong =(

If u find a solution, please explain it in detail since I am not a programmer and only have little experience with going this 'deep' into files and paths etc ...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found it myself I think.
I read somewhere that using gcc in stead of g++ could help and after copying the missing files to a bunch of folders it worked :D